# file runs in windows 7 (albeit with an error message), but in windows 10 it doesn't get that far, it says "This program has been damage..."

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I have an executable file that runs to an extent in windows 7 (albeit with an error message), but in windows 10 it doesn't get that far, it says "This program has been damaged, possibly by a bad sector of the hard drive or a virus. Please reinstall it"

Here is [the file](http://ge.tt/7rqUPlx2) (SHA1: 594166bb3c5302e20808605b53b53c1cd5e26430). I had to rename it to .txt to upload it but you can rename it to `.exe` .

I checked it in VirusTotal and it came up as not having any virus/malware.

On Windows 7 it says "extract error", that's fine..

But the strange thing is on Windows 10, I get this error:

> This program has been damaged, possibly by a bad sector of the hard drive or a virus. Please reinstall it

[image: This program has been damaged, ...]

What is it about Windows 10 that means it doesn't even attempt to execute the file, and is there any way to get Windows 10 to execute it as Windows 7 does?

Comment: I get on Windows 10 x64 "Extract error: 9".

Comment: So many question I have. Is it a setup or a standalone executable? Did you check any dll dependency graph? What error in Win7?

Comment: @harrymc ah maybe just my windows 10 x64 then..strange.

Comment: @Biswapriyo not sure i think it's a setup.. I didn't check any dll dependency, how would you suggest I check that?  In win7 I got the same error harry managed to get in win10.. i'd like to get that error in win10..

Comment: Since I am not going to download a random file off the internet, please provide the necessary information, to download the file from it's the original source.

Comment: Looking into the message further it can only be caused by security software.  Please edit your question to identify any and all security software you have installed.

Comment: AT Ramhound it occurs on a fresh windows 10 pro installation I did.. and the message occurs on another computer with win10 that I got from ebay. Why do you say it can only be cause by security software?  I think it'd have to be something native to windows 10, though harry doesn't get that happening.

Comment: @barlop a fresh Windows installation may still contain some anti-malware solution. On Windows 10 the Windows Defender will be the default, but for OEM installations it could be _anything_. So the question is indeed valid. You will also want to inspect `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store` to see whether some compatibility rule was applied to the executable. The ACT may provide further insight (the Compatibility Administrator in particular).

Comment: Also, given all of you claim to use Windows 10, perhaps it's time to name the respective releases (or build numbers) rather than merely "Windows 10"? I am getting that same error on Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations (1903) _with_ Windows Defender "realtime" scan and other security features disabled. I even get it when artificially trying to run it in compat mode for Windows 7.

Comment: Going by the optional header's `SizeOfImage` field (2772992 == 0x2A5000) the file that I have downloaded at 1101824 Bytes size (and with SHA1 594166bb3c5302e20808605b53b53c1cd5e26430) the message that the file is damaged may well be correct, btw. I checked, because I expected to find an overlay (i.e. `SizeOfImage` being considerably smaller than the file size, as can be found in many installers/setups).

Comment: @0xC0000022L  When you say you get that error do you mean the error about bad sector?  The "Extract error..." is   ok because there are perhaps meant to be other files.  But the error about the bad sector is what i'm trying to get past.  Perhaps a hex editor could be used to fix that inconsistency(eg by adjusting the sizeofimage field), and get past that 'bad sector' error?

Comment: @barlop indeed, that's the one I meant (bad sector).

Comment: @0xC0000022L any chance that a hex editor can get past that inconsistency?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97930/discussion-between-0xc0000022l-and-barlop).

Answer (score 1):

> What is it about Windows 10 that means it doesn't even attempt to execute the file and is there any way to get Windows 10 to execute it as Windows 7 does?

**The file is not directly compatible with Windows 10.**  I suspect the application is not compatible, due to the changes surrounding UAC with Windows 8+, which is the reason "it works" on Windows 7.

> is there any way to get Windows 10 to execute it as Windows 7 does?

You can use **Windows 95** or **Windows 98** compatibility mode.  I was able to get an `Extract error: 9` on both my **Windows 10 x86** and **Windows 10 x64** VM

Comment: I will not speculate the reason it worked for another user.  If I am right about the fact it's an incompatibility with the changes to UAC, and the difference between the way default permissions are granted to a process on Windows 7 and Windows 8+ if the other user had UAC disabled that would be the most likely explanation.

Comment: Well, the ACT lets you see and manipulate the shims applied to a given executable. So no speculation necessary. Just downloading, installing and then looking it up. Heuristics are used to apply shims. This holds true especially for "known" installer/setup stubs. But I agree that likely some "policy change" is the cause for the different behavior encountered. But since the OP only ever mentioned _in the discussion (not the question)_ that 1803 was used on one of the machines and harrymc didn't indicate anything at all, we're left to assume.

Comment: One more thing, you need to download the ADK these days to get the Compatibility Administrator and other ACT tools.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - My tests were on 1809/1803/1903 VMs.  I right clicked on and configured compatability mode, ACT isn't installed. The VMs were based of an original (stand alone) clone of a single Windows Vista machine that has been clonned and upgrade to various versions of Windows over the years.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - I know that there isn't a significant difference between a "clean install" and an "upgrade install".  I also got a chance to test my physical Windows 10 machines and they all behaved identical.